# C++ unknown type name template - Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, compiler-construction, tizen

I'm trying to import some sources intro my project. And I came across this error when trying to compile.

`6:1: error: unknown type name 'template'`

The header that gets the error looks something like this.

```
template <typename T> T MyMin(T a, T b)
  {  return a < b ? a : b; }

template <class T> inline T MyMax(T a, T b)
  {  return a > b ? a : b; }

template <class T> inline int MyCompare(T a, T b)
  {  return a < b ? -1 : (a == b ? 0 : 1); }

inline int BoolToInt(bool value)
  { return (value ? 1: 0); }

inline bool IntToBool(int value)
  { return (value != 0); }
```

- I'm using the Tizen SDK 2.0 which is based on Eclipse Indigo.
- I have Cygwin installed and the default C++ compiler used is clang++

If you need more details just let me know.

Do you have any ideea what the problem might be?

Comment: What line of your code snippet has the error? This is some strange code. Standard library already has min and max functions.

Comment: I know the functions exist already, but I have this sources that I have to import into my current project. Can't really change their structure. Just make the best effort to compile them without modifying the code to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that my `MyLibrary.h` was compiled using the **gcc** because it was called inside a .c source file.

This was due to a multitude of includes which all led to the same file.

Because the **gcc** was used, the keyword **template** wasn't recognized.

Fixed it by making the **g++** compile the source file where `MyLibrary.h` was included.